# requires_grad = False seems not working in my case

Tags: pytorch

I received a `Cannot insert a Tensor that requires grad as a constant. Consider making it a parameter or input, or detaching the gradient` error with tensor `W`.

`W` has the size of `(10,10)` and `grad_fn=<DivBackward0>`. The error happens at the second line

```
def muy(self, x):
    V = torch.tensor(self.W - self.lambda_ * torch.eye(self.ENCODING_DIM), requires_grad=False)
    return -0.5 * V.inverse().mm(self.b + self.lambda_ * x[:, None])
```

Other vars, values taken at the time of the error

- `self.lambda_`: `1.0`
- `self.ENCODING_DIM`: `10`
- `self.b`: `torch.Size([10, 1])`, `requires_grad=True`
- `x`: `torch.Size([3, 1, 10])`, `grad_fn=<MulBackward0>`

How could I set the result of `muy` as just an ingredient of the leaf node, so grad through `V` is required?

I tried this monstrosity, to no avail

```
def muy(self, x):
    V_inv = np.linalg.inv(self.V.detach().numpy())
    x_numpy = x[:, None].detach().numpy()
    temp= -0.5 * np.matmul(V_inv, self.b.detach().numpy() + self.lambda_ * x_numpy)
    return temp
```

Why I cared about this JIT:
I wanted to use tensorboard to visualize my model, if I understand the error messages right, the visualzing models use `Tracer`

**EDIT**
This still gives the same error, `W` or `W.detach()`

```
with torch.no_grad():
    V = self.W - self.lambda_ * torch.eye(self.ENCODING_DIM)
    return -0.5 * V.inverse().mm(self.b + self.lambda_ * x[:, None])
```

Comment: Can you try putting the entire function body within: `with torch.no_grad():`?

Comment: @Mercury please see my edit :)

Comment: After some debugging, I can say that the loss is decreasing, and the network seems to learn something. I fixed a lot of things, but the most important thing is to not treat tensors as numpy array, and try to vectorize as much as possible. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

```
V = torch.tensor(self.W - self.lambda_ * torch.eye(self.ENCODING_DIM), requires_grad=False)
```

What you are trying to do here doesn't make much sense. `torch.tensor(value)` can only be created if the `value` is scalar (e.g. Python's `5`), while you are trying to fit `torch.Tensor` there.

What you should do is simply this:

```
V = self.W - self.lambda_ * torch.eye(self.ENCODING_DIM)
```

If you want to detach `self.W` for some reason you can do this:

```
V = self.W.detach() - self.lambda_ * torch.eye(self.ENCODING_DIM)
```

(**this will make a copy of `self.W` with `requires_grad` set to `False`**).

You could also use `torch.no_grad()` context manager so this operation will not be recorded on the graph which will have the same effect on the graph (but only in this case, not in general and you won't make copy of `self.W` so it is advised to do that):

```
with torch.no_grad():
    V = self.W - self.lambda_ * torch.eye(self.ENCODING_DIM)
```

### Code to reproduce

Can't reproduce this exact issue based on your code description, see below:

```
import torch

lambda_ = 1.0
W = torch.randn(10, 10, requires_grad=True)

ENCODING_DIM = 10
b = torch.randn(10, 1, requires_grad=True)
x = torch.randn(3, 1, 10, requires_grad=True)


with torch.no_grad():
    V = W - lambda_ * torch.eye(ENCODING_DIM)
    result = -0.5 * V.inverse().mm(b + lambda_ * x[:, None])

print(result)
```

This code gives the following (different!) error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "foo.py", line 13, in
>
> result = -0.5 * V.inverse().mm(b + lambda_ * x[:, None]) RuntimeError: matrices expected, got 2D, 4D tensors at
> /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:36

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensor.html#torch.tensor says data could by numpy array too

Comment: @MinhTriet Cannot reproduce, see minimal code sample I have tested. It is a different error and __not__ related to your previous one which is clearly about creating `torch.Tensor` from another `torch.Tensor`. If this error exists it happens in different line. Also what's your PyTorch version? `1.6.0` here, update dependencies if they are really outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about shape of matrixes.

in this line `return -0.5 * V.inverse().mm(self.b + self.lambda_ * x[:, None])`,
`V.inverse()`shape is `[10, 10]`, `b` shape is `[10, 1]` and `x[:, None]` shape is`[3, 1, 1, 10]`. These shapes are not good for calculating what you want. especially that of `x[:, None]`.